# Issue locating button in Safari using Watir

Tags: ruby, safari, webdriver, watir

I have weird issue with locating button in Safari.
This is the button's html:

```
<span id="submit-btn" class="btn">Submit</span>
```

When I'm trying to locate button by ID it can't find it

```
browser.span(:css => "span[id=submit-btn]")
browser.span(:id => "submit-btn")
```

But when I'm locating it by text it finds the button properly:

```
browser.span(:text => "Submit")
```

What is possible issue? Is it issues with safari webdriver? I am running on Safari 11.1 with native webdriver.
Tried couple of different ways to locate button by xpath and from parent elements, but no luck.
Note: every way to locate the button works of windows with Chrome.

Comment: try `browser.spans(id: 'submit-btn').size`. There's a decent chance you have more than one submit button on the page.

Comment: ah, I didn't see that last part. Try `browser.spans.map(&:id)` should show you what the id values are. perhaps safari has spaces in there that aren't being handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `spans` instead of `span`. This worked for me:

```
browser.spans(:id => "submit-btn").first
```

Comment: `#spans` will return an `SpanCollection` not a `Span`, you'd at least need to add `.first`

Comment: @titusfortner - good point. I edited my answer to reflect that